# Question about Hopf algebra and actions on endomorphisms rings

Tags: modules, representation-theory, hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra and $M, N$ two left $H$-modules, then we can define a left $H$-module structure on $\mathrm{Hom}(M,N)$ given by $(h * f)(m) = h_1 f(S(h_2) m)$, where $S$ is the antipode. My question is kind of further from that, I want to show that $*$ acts on $\mathrm{Hom}(M, M)$ such that
$$
  h * (f \circ g) = (h_1 * f) \circ (h_2 * g)
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  h * \mathrm{id}_M = \epsilon(h) \mathrm{id}_M \,.
$$

The second identity is easier to show: given $m \in M$, we have
$$
  (h * \mathrm{id}_M)(m)
  = h_1 \mathrm{id}_M(S(h_2) m)
  = h_1 S(h_2) m \,,
$$
but $h_1 S(h_2) = \epsilon(h)$, so $(h * \mathrm{id}_M)(m) = \epsilon(h) m = \epsilon(h) \mathrm{id}_M(m)$.

Now I'm stuck on $h * (f \circ g) = (h_1 * f) \circ (h_2 * g)$, because for each $m \in M$ the left side is
$$
  (h * (f \circ g))(m) = h_1 f(g(S(h_2) m))
$$
and for the other side we have
$$
  ((h_1 * f ) \circ (h_2 * g))(m)
  = (h_1 * f)(h_{2,1} g(S(h_{2,2}) m))
  = h_{1,1}f(S(h_{1,2})h_{2,1}g(S(h_{2,2})m)) \,.
$$

I don't know how to rewrite that expression to arrive at some equality, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting your notation correctly, then what you need is to apply coassociativity. Using Sweedler notation, this means that your $h_{1,1} \otimes h_{1,2}\otimes h_{2,1}\otimes h_{2,2}$ can really be reindexed as $h_{(1)}\otimes h_{(2)}\otimes h_{(3)}\otimes h_{(4)}$, because $(\Delta\otimes\operatorname{id}) \circ \Delta = (\operatorname{id}\otimes \Delta)\circ \Delta$ and so on.

The identity you want is $h \ast (f\circ g) = (h_{(1)}\ast f) \circ (h_{(2)}\ast g)$. You have expanded the right hand side using the definition of the $H$ action and got $ (h_{(1)}\ast f) \circ (h_{(2)}\ast g)(m) = h_{(1)} f(S(h_{(2)}) h_{(3)} g(S(h_{(4)})m))$. The factors $S(h_{(2)}) h_{(3)}$ can be collapsed using $S(h_{(1)})h_{(2)} = \epsilon(h)$, which can then be pulled out of $f$, so we can simplify the result to $h_{(1)} \epsilon(h_{(2)}) f(g(S(h_{(3)}m)) = h_{(1)} f(g(S(h_{2})m)) = h\ast(f\circ g) (m)$.